# CSV file generated correctly but with wrong format when is downloaded

Tags: php, http-headers, opencsv, fputcsv

I am a beginner student of PHP and i am doing some practice by coding a script to generate a CSV file.
Once that the csv file is generated , the format is correct as I've expected :
[See the attached :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8muQ.jpg)

But if i add the download option the csv is generated wrongly with all the PHP page (i can see all the code)

[Here the picture of the wrong csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlLne.jpg)

Could you help me to find the issue ?

Here the code :

```
 <?php

    include("db.php");
    session_start();


    $sql = "SELECT isocode FROM test_geo ORDER BY isocode";
    $result_csv = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    //facebook csv creation //
    $filename = 'test.csv';
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $headers = ['key', 'country'];

    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    foreach ($result_csv as $key => $id) {
        $new = array_push($id, "country");


        fputcsv($fp, $id);
        var_dump($id);
    }

    fclose($fp);





    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the code for the download :                                            
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv');

Comment: `var_dump` is an issue that's why it's giving you all array, object words in your CSV. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: I removed it but now the downloaded csv has only the html attributes  and the php ones are missing...

Comment: Try `echo` like `echo $id`

Comment: You are writing both to a file on disk and the HTTP response, do one or the other, not both, and probably only the latter. `var_dump` is for debugging, nothing else. `echo` if you want to output. The provided screenshot makes it appear as if there’s more code, please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=result_file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$output = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($new as $row) {
  fputcsv($outputt, $row);
}
fclose($outputt);
exit();
```

Comment: As it stands, this appears to output “file download headers”, writes a file to disk on the server, then dies, outputting zero bytes to the client, am I missing something? Did you instead to set $fp to a stream blind to the HTTP response?

Comment: `$output` vs. `$outputt`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you put the header statements at the top of your script, so the download data includes the HTML codes too (like below...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><meta charset=...... >
```

You may use **ob_flush()** and set **header** (at the appropriate position of the code) so that the file will be correctly downloaded as csv when it is generated.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");


$sql = "SELECT isocode FROM test_geo ORDER BY isocode";
$result_csv = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


$data=array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_csv, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $ok=$row["isocode"] . "," . "Country";
   array_push($data ,$ok);
}


ob_flush();
$filename="ok1.csv";
$csvData = join("\n", $data);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
die($csvData);

?>
```